# When to use onTokenRefresh?

Tags: phonegap, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am building an app using PhoneGap and using FCM to push notifications. Currently, the code executes getToken and onNotification every time the app runs (no login is necessary) and I can send notifications to the user. Do I need to use onTokenRefresh?

Answer (score 0):

No. I had build and application using Quasar,Apache Cordova and the FCM. The onNotification method was enough to receive the notifications on the device.

The `onNotification()` method sets a event listener to the FCM, and each time you send a notification, the device will receive it.